# Execution import error after success pip install compilation

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, pypy, crossbar

### My trouble

On clean Ubuntu 16.04 environment, I want to install and use Crossbar.io.

I have already **installed pypy from ppa, virtualenv** and activate a new pypy virtualenv.

I had some error while installing crossbar via command `pip install crossbar` but solved using this build command:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/python2.7" crossbar
```

Now when launching crossbar with `crossbar version` I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/bin/crossbar", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('crossbar==17.6.1.post3', 'console_scripts', 'crossbar')()
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/crossbar/controller/cli.py", line 62, in <module>
    from crossbar.controller.node import _read_release_pubkey, _read_node_pubkey
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/crossbar/controller/node.py", line 44, in <module>
    from nacl.signing import SigningKey
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/signing.py", line 19, in <module>
    import nacl.bindings
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/bindings/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nacl.bindings.crypto_box import (
  File "/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/bindings/crypto_box.py", line 18, in <module>
    from nacl._sodium import ffi, lib
ImportError: unable to load extension module '/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': /home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _Py_NoneStruct
```

I try adding path by settings environment variable before launching but no success:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

### My environment

- Ubuntu 16.04 / 4.4.0-87-generic
- Python 2.7.13 (5.8.0+dfsg-2~ppa2~ubuntu16.04, Jun 17 2017, 18:50:19)
- [PyPy 5.8.0 with GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
- pip 9.0.1 from /home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages (python 2.7)

Results of ldd on failing library:

```
ldd -r /home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff31ddd000)
    libsodium.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.18 (0x00007fe336153000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe335f0c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe335b41000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000564659a68000)
undefined symbol: _Py_NoneStruct    (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyObject_CallMethod   (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyEval_RestoreThread  (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_FromVoidPtr    (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyArg_UnpackTuple (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyErr_Occurred    (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyImport_ImportModule (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyLong_FromUnsignedLong   (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyInt_FromLong    (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
undefined symbol: PyEval_SaveThread (/home/visiboost/gmm_pypy_env2/site-packages/nacl/_sodium.pypy-41-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Have you any ideas ?

Comment: I think you're running ``pip`` with CPython.  In order to install PyPy packages, you have to run it with PyPy.

Comment: Good idea but that was not the case, I am into my pypy virtualenv when running the pip install command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using cpython headers with pypy so the `--global-option="-I/usr/include/python2.7"` is wrong. As documented [here](https://pypy.org/download.html#installing-more-modules) and [here](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html) you probably need to install the `pypy-dev` package so that you can build packages with pypy, much as you need `python-dev` to 
build packages with python.

Edit: looking at the crossbar [documentation](http://crossbar.io/docs/Installation-on-Linux/#install-for-pypy), they do not recommend using `apt get` at all, and also recommend compiling CPython from source, which is why there is no mention of the `python-dev` package.

Comment: Thanks you're right ! I don't solve building troubles with good library using python-dev. I have installed pypy-dev package and run again the pip install command and it's working ! Thanks a lot, you save my day ;)

Comment: Perfect solution! I should add you will also need to rebuild all wheels and clear pip's cache after this. `pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --no-binary :all: package_name`

Answer (score 0):

Solved using @mattip response : install pypy-dev package via `apt-get install pypy-dev` and run again pip install to rebuild modules using good libraries `pip install --no-cache-dir crossbar`.

It's now working well for me !